# UNEDITED "Expected ';' at end of decleration"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I'm a newcomer to objective-C, but i have a problem.
When i open a new project and specify the filepath, but when the main project window opens i
immidiatly get an issue.

```
1. #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
2. 
3. @interface ViewController : UIViewController
4. 
5. @end
```

I get an "Expected ';' at end of decleration" issue on line 4. I have not done anything to it, it just opens like that. What is the problem??

Comment: The issue is not in the posted code sample. I guess it may be in the shared header file of your project. Did you changed something there?

Comment: Nope, nothing, the above is just comments..

Comment: did you created the file using Xcode? if no, is there any special UTF-8 character (whitespace) in the text file? unicode supports at least 20 different space characters, they are invisible for the eyes, but they are not the standard `U+0020`, and the compiler would find all of them problematic.